# Is it possible to run selenium test cases on cloud?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-testing

I am using `maven` to run my selenium test cases .I have taken the whole code to my `digital ocean` `Ubuntu` server ,I have installed or configured all necessary plugins like `chromedriver`,`maven`..etc . 
On running the command `mvn test` I am getting the following error .

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 28572
Only local connections are allowed.
May 19, 2017 4:56:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
May 19, 2017 4:57:17 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 63.761 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
invokeBrowser(datum.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 63.281 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 85 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'devopspipe', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-78-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 7c4d43849026d2b42c83fa6d39230969
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:882)
    at datum.UtilsMethods.browserInvoke(UtilsMethods.java:99)
    at datum.LoginTest.invokeBrowser(LoginTest.java:20)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  LoginTest.invokeBrowser:20 » NoSuchSession no such session
  (Driver info: chr...

Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-19T04:57:18+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project DataVisualisation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/sample-selenium-datum/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

If there is any other way of running the test cases on cloud please suggest and if I need to provide any other information let me know .
My browser invocation code :

```
else if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/arima/chromeDriver/chromedriver");
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/selenium-drivers/chromedriver");
            capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            driver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(capability);

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
        }
```

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error stack trace `Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator` that your `TestNG652Configurator` class is error prone. Can you consider showing us the `TestNG652Configurator` class? Thanks

Comment: In it is not possible to invoke the browser that is why it's giving the error .I have attached the code please check.

Comment: I would suggest to start it simple, first execute your code as a `TestNG test` first, on success execute as a `TestNG suite`, on success convert it into `Maven` project. That would make things go smooth. Thanks

Comment: The code is working fine when I am running it on local machine .It is giving error while running it on server .And for continuous testing I need to run it on server.

Comment: Can't agree more, your chromedriver code block still includes `driver.manage().window().maximize();`, correct them first. Next consider looking at your stack trace `FAILURE! - in TestSuite` its clear your execution environment setup have some flaws. Try executing `TestNG` tests from CLI first. Then integrate maven.